# Understanding minimal polynomials in several variables

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Consider a field extension $K \subseteq L$ and some $a \in L^{n+1}$. Suppose one fixes two integers $d, e>0$. Can one characterize all polynomials $P(x) \in K[x_0,\dots x_n]$ such that $P(a) = 0$, $\operatorname{deg}(P) = d$ (where this is understood to be the total degree) and $\operatorname{deg}_{x_n}(P) = e$? (assuming at least one such exists).

Comment: I was about to write a lengthier comment, but then I noticed the requirement $a\in K^{n+1}$. What stops you from writing all the polynomials in terms of $x_i-a_i$ and just counting? Basically reducing the question to the case $a=(0,0,\ldots,0)$. The term *minimal polynomials* in the title threw me off a bit. There is nothing mysterious about the minimal polynomials of $a_i$s, when they are all elements of $K$.

Comment: The space $V_{d,e}$ of polynomials $P$ satisfying the conditions given is a finite dimensional vector space. One can even find a basis by looking at linear combinations of pairs of monomials which satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Well, I'm sure they're not mysterious, but I was wondering how much of an explicit description of them one could give (I am actually working with a valued field, and I'd like to know how many of them satisfy a certain valuation-theoretic condition on their derivatives, so a good starting point would be writing them down).

Comment: Ah, @JyrkiLahtonen I see what you mean, sorry. I mean that a comes from some extension L of K! I'll edit.

Comment: Ok. That makes more sense. And a more interesting question. It's too late an hour here for me to attempt an answer (or look for possible duplicates). Algebraic geometry has a lot to say about this. For example with $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $n=2$, we get very different looking answers with $a=(1,1,\sqrt2)$, $a=(1,\sqrt2,1+\sqrt2)$, $a=(1,\sqrt2,\cos(2\pi/7))$, $a=(1,\pi,\pi^2)$ or even
$a=(e^{\sqrt2},e^{\sqrt3},e^\sqrt{5})$.